# Django Mysql Database Rename Error even after deleting table

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am using mysql in my django project. In model.py i changed my primary key.For that i got an error.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1025, "Error on rename of './newdb
>   /#sql-4ac_29' to './newdb/companies2_album' (errno: 150)")

From model.py i deleted the table and the corresponding table also. And now i dont have any song table.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

class Stock(models.Model):
  ticker=models.CharField(max_length=10)
  open=models.FloatField()
  close=models.FloatField()
  volume=models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.ticker


class Stock2(models.Model):
  ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  open = models.FloatField()
  close = models.FloatField()
  volume = models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.ticker
    '''
    (deleted)
    class Band(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  genre=models.CharField(max_length=10)
  formationyear=models.IntegerField()
  country=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  lineup = models.CharField(max_length=80)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to="bandimages")

  def __str__(self):
    return self.ticker


class Album(models.Model):
  id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  'bandid=models.ForeignKey(Band,on_delete=models.CASCADE)'
  releaseyear=models.IntegerField()
  songscount= models.IntegerField()
  image = models.ImageField()

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  'albumid=models.ForeignKey(Album,on_delete=models.CASCADE)'
  lyric=models.CharField(max_length=200)
  like=models.IntegerField()
  dislike=models.IntegerField()
  utubelink=models.CharField(max_length=100)


  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
   (deleted)
   '''
```

Still i get this error.

I cant understand how it happens. I changed the database also.Reinstall mysqlserver.But nothing can fix this.

Comment: Format the code properly.

Comment: When are you getting this error? Have you run makemigrations and migrate?